# Kotlin regexp matching parenthesis content

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm trying to match parenthesis content using Kotlin.

I found that regex should be `/\(([^)]+)\)/` but can't have it working in Kotlin.

```
val pattern = """/\(([^)]+)\)/""".toRegex(RegexOption.LITERAL)

val text = "aaaa (ferf ) veffef (frr) refef"

fun main() {
    println(pattern.matches(text))
}
```

returns `false`.

Comment: Solved my issue thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the initial and trailing slashes as you need to define the regex pattern using a string literal, and you need to only capture any chars other than parentheses inside parentheses and use `findAll` rather than `matches` to find all matches.

Use

```
val m = """\(([^()]*)\)""".toRegex()
val text = "aaaa (ferf ) veffef (frr) refef" 
val results =  m.findAll(text).map{it.groupValues[1]}.toList()
println(results)
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://rextester.com/NDWH67284).